# How to tie a dry fly above a wet fly when fly fishing?

Tags: fly-fishing

Most fly fishing with wet flies is done with just single wet fly and a strike indicator but it's also possible to do it with a dry fly instead of a strike indicator (this lets you do both at the same time).

Sometimes fish will try to eat the strike indicator, and this would let you catch them instead of missing.

How do you **tie the dry fly onto the line in place of a strike indicator**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple.

1. Tie the dry fly on the end like normal.
2. Take the wet fly and tie it onto an appropriately sized length of tippet (between 13-24 inches)
3. Tie the end of tippet with the dry fly to either the bend of the hook on the dry fly or to the eye of the dry fly (if you can get the line through the eye) with the same type of knot.

Comment: There are a lot of words here that might not be familiar to new fly fishers, maybe add a photo?

Comment: @JamesJenkins All of the above is perfectly fine if you know anything about fly fishing and you have to know how to tie the flies onto the end before you can try this

Comment: You might want to check if it’s legal where you fish. Some states prohibit multiple baits and hooks, or there may be a limit to the number of hooks permitted in a single rig.

Comment: IMHO tying to the bend is superior both in terms of its simplicity and fish-ability. I feel it casts better and tangles less than tying to the dry fly's eye.